# how to deal with jump to other app when test monkey with UIAutomation?

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, monkey

I'm testing my app with UIAutomation(monkey), and it may click a button and open safari,
how can I do if I want to go back to my testing app ?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the app from ever leaving the foreground by turning on Guided access.

On the device. You can enable Guided Access at Settings > General > Accessibility > Guided Access.

Once your app is open you can tap the home button 3 times and turn it on.

With UIAutomation, add a delay right at the beginning of the Monkey script.  When running the script, this will give you some time to start Guided Access after the app was launched.

More on Guided Access: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5509